# Race condition / async calls in web3 database writes

Tags: web3js, nodejs

I'm using web3.eth.filter to listen for specific topics, pull data from those logs, and write to a database. Part of the database update function checks the previous document (sorted by block number) and adds to the value. I'm having an issue where the database writes are out of order (and it's pulling the wrong previous block) so the end total is wrong. What can be fixed in the below code to ensure the ordering is correct?

```
require( './db' )
const BigNumber = require('bignumber.js')
const mongoose  = require( 'mongoose' )
const Block  = mongoose.model('Block')
const Web3 = require('web3');

web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

var addresses = [
    '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001',
  ]

var blockUpdate = function(id, num, txData) {

  Block.find({block: txData.block}, function (err, b) {
    if (!b.length) {
      Block.find({ 'block': { $lt : txData.block }}, {}, { sort: { block: -1}, limit: 1}, function (err, prevblock) {
        return Block.findOneAndUpdate({'block': txData.block}, { $set: { "total": prevblock[0].total + num, "timestamp": txData.timestamp }}, { upsert: true}, function( err, res) {
          if ( typeof err !== 'undefined' && err ) {
           console.log('Error: Aborted due to error on ' + err);
           process.exit(9)
          }
        })
      })

    } else {
      return Block.findOneAndUpdate({'block': txData.block}, { $inc: { "total": num } }, { upsert: true }, function( err, res ){
        if ( typeof err !== 'undefined' && err ) {
         console.log('Error: Aborted due to error on ' + err);
         process.exit(9)
        }
      });
    }
  });

}

var filter = web3.eth.filter({fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest', address: addresses});

filter.watch(function(error, logs) {

  if(logs) {

    var time = web3.eth.getBlock(logs.blockNumber).timestamp;

    var topic = logs.topics[0].slice(0,10)

    switch(topic)
    {
    case '0x000000':

      var id = logs.data.slice(260,266)
      var num = Number(parseNumber(logs.data.slice(-36), 18))
      txData.txHash = logs.transactionHash
      txData.block = logs.blockNumber
      txData.txType = 'test1'
      txData.txData = num
      txData.timestamp = time * 1000
      var test = blockUpdate(id, num, txData)
      break;

    case '0x000001':

      var id = logs.data.slice(260,266)
      var num = Number(parseNumber(logs.data.slice(-36), 18))
      txData.txHash = logs.transactionHash
      txData.block = logs.blockNumber
      txData.txType = 'test2'
      txData.txData = num
      txData.timestamp = time * 1000
      var test = blockUpdate(id, -num, txData)
      break;

    default:

    }

  } else {
    console.log(error)
  }

})
```